# How does HttpSession invalidate() actually work?

Tags: http, session, servlets, jakarta-ee

in documentation it says:

> **public void invalidate()**
>
> Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

Does that mean that just the references to the attribute objects are removed or the objects themselves are destroyed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `invalidate` method causes the web application container to unbind (not destroy) all references of the web application to the HttpSession Object, and then destroys (removes from JVM) the HttpSession Object .